# AS3 - Position symbols in symbols according to stage values

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, symbols

I want to place a symbol (symbol2) inside another symbol (symbol1). Then I want to position that symbol (symbol2) to for example x = 50 (The stage's x = 50, not symbol1's x = 50)

```
symbol1.symbol2.x = 50;
```

This places symbol2 to the symbol1's coordinate system.
Therefore; if symbol1.x = 50 and symbol1.symbol2.x = 50, symbol2 will be placed on the stages value 100.

I don't know if this was understandable. I does anyone have an idea of how to do this easily?

Comment: take a look at [DisplayObject.globalToLocal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal()) and localToGlobal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`globalToLocal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal()) to convert stage coordinates to a symbol's coordinates:

```
var stageCoordinates:Point = new Point(50, 0);
var symbol1Coordinates:Point = symbol1.globalToLocal(stageCoordinates);
symbol2.x = symbol1Coordinates.x;
```

Or condensed to:

```
symbol2.x = symbol1.globalToLocal(new Point(50, 0)).x;
```